# How to exclude {} from another type?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type

```
type Z = {a: number} | {} | {b: boolean} | {c: string} | ...;
```

How can I obtain a the same but without `{}`?

```
type Y = Exclude<Z, {}>;
```

⇧Results in `Y = never`, because all variants are *assignable* to `{}`, so get excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jcalz's answer is awesome, and after I understand it, I think maybe there is a way based on jcalz's, which can exclude the very same type.

```
type ExcludeExact<T, U> = T extends any ? U extends T ? (T extends U ? never : T) : T : never;
```

This works as you want:

```
type Y = ExcludeExact<Z, {}>
// type Y = { a: number } | { b: boolean } | { c: string }
```

and works also in this way:

```
type Y = ExcludeExact<Z, {a: number}>
// type Y = { } | { b: boolean } | { c: string }
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes jcalz's is awesome but this is even better. I'm trying to grok how this works...

Comment: Anyway I think this should be offered by TypeScript, you should open a PR, many people would find this useful

Comment: I've just started learning TS and the main idea belongs to jcalz. So I don't think I should open a PR :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own `Exclude`-like type function like `ExcludeSupertypes<T, U>` which splits `T` into its union members and excludes any such members which are *supertypes* of `U` instead of *subtypes* of `U`:

```
type ExcludeSupertypes<T, U> = T extends any ? U extends T ? never : T : never;
```

This works as you want on `Z`:

```
type Y = ExcludeSupertypes<Z, {}>
// type Y = { a: number } | { b: boolean } | { c: string }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAWlC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXygB9kLqUDMCB7JgGwlS3KuSgGNMAZ2DEAllgDm5ALAAoOaEhQAogA8+rHABMIAZRyRiiiIIA8AFQA0UAKoA+BFHNQIq4BCxbBaLCCgB+Wxc3Dy8nAOwIADcSKExnTCxokgBuOQVwaABNRzUNbT0DEmMzGGskMjs5AHpqqGMoHMQUDGx8IlJaXgYoZjYOLi6UAShhMUkZWSA)

Comment: Nice, `T extends any` needed to trigger distribution over union?